# JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null - Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

The Problem is that every time I like to run it in Chrome the error message pops up. The days/hours and minutes should turn red every time they change.

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 30, 2018 15:50:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Blink
    if (seconds == 59){
        document.getElementById("minutes").style.color = 'red';

        if(minutes == 59){
            document.getElementById("hours").style.color = 'red';

            if(hour == 24){
            document.getElementById("days").style.color = 'red';
            }
        }   
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("minutes").style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById("hours").style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById("days").style.color = 'black';
    }

    // Delete Day, Hour and Minute Timer if they are 0
    if (days !== 0 && hours !== 0 && minutes !== 0 && seconds !== 0){
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Noch " + days + " Tage " + hours + " Stunden "
        + minutes + " Minuten und " + seconds + " Sekunden bis zur Fertigstellung des Spiels";

        if (days === 0){
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Noch " + hours + " Stunden "
        + minutes + " Minuten und " + seconds + " Sekunden bis zur Fertigstellung des Spiels";

            if (hours === 0){
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Noch " + minutes + " Minuten und " + seconds + " Sekunden bis zur Fertigstellung des Spiels";

                if (minutes === 0){
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Noch " + seconds + " Sekunden bis zur Fertigstellung des Spiels";
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Zu Ende";
    }

    // show hidden content if days / 3 = mod 0      
    if (days % 3 !== 0){
        document.getElementById("special").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: There's no element with id `minutes`, `hours`, `days`, and/or `special` in the DOM (when the function is executed).

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues here.

The first is that you're trying to use `getElementById` with elements that don't appear to exist yet ("minutes", "hours", "days"). Elements with those IDs need to exist in the DOM before they can be accessed using the `getElementById` method.

One way to address this is to wrap your current variables in `<span>` tags and give them each a unique ID that you can access later.

```
var daysElement = `<span id="days">${days}</span>`,
    hoursElement = `<span id="hours">${hours}</span>`,
    minutesElement = `<span id="minutes">${minutes}</span>`,
    secondsElement = `<span id="seconds">${days}</span>`;
```

Now if you add these elements to the `innerHTML` of the "time" element (instead of just the numbers themselves), you'll be able to target their ids and change their style afterwards.

```
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Noch " 
+ hoursElement + " Stunden " + minutesElement + " Minuten und " 
+ secondsElement + " Sekunden bis zur Fertigstellung des Spiels";
```

Lastly, you'll need to make sure your order of operations is correct. Move the following code to *below* the part where you change the `innerHTML` of "time", so that the elements exist in the DOM before you try to change their style properties.

```
if (seconds == 59){
    document.getElementById("minutes").style.color = 'red';

    if(minutes == 59){
        document.getElementById("hours").style.color = 'red';

        if(hour == 24){
        document.getElementById("days").style.color = 'red';
        }
    }   
}
else{
    document.getElementById("minutes").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("hours").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("days").style.color = 'black';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not with JS it seems.
Can not read property style of null means style property of the object you are trying to access is null.
Please check all the document.getElementById api you are using for the elements have correct id present in html elements(that you are using in code).

Also check in your browser console accessing the element using document.getElementById api.

Please add your script at the end of the body tag so that the elements get loaded, if it is a loading issue.

Then also if it is not resolved, add debugger to the js lines and check why the element is not availble.

Comment: _"**Can not read property style of null** means style property of the object you are trying to access is null."_ - No the error message is absolutely clear. What ever is left of `.style` is `null`

Comment: by saying left of .style you mean the left hand side of .style?  @Andreas